# i have videos list when i select row video will play on another view how to stop and come back for table view

Tags: iphone

```
  if (indexPath.row==0) 
  {
    NSString *urlAsString = [[NSBundle mainBundle]  pathForResource: [self.array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] ofType:@"mov"];

    NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:urlAsString];

    MPMoviePlayerController *myPlayer = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] init];
    myPlayer.shouldAutoplay = YES;
    myPlayer.repeatMode = MPMovieRepeatModeOne;
    myPlayer.fullscreen = YES;
    myPlayer.movieSourceType = MPMovieSourceTypeFile;
    myPlayer.scalingMode = MPMovieScalingModeAspectFit;
    myPlayer.contentURL =[NSURL fileURLWithPath:urlAsString];
    [self.view addSubview:myPlayer.view];

    [myPlayer.view setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 400)];
    [myPlayer setFullscreen:YES animated:YES];
    [myPlayer play];
  }
```

i have one button in `MPMoviePlayerController` called done when i click on done button i need  to come back to my `tableview` plz help me any one

Answer (score 0):

MPMoviePlayerController *myPlayer declare global and init . and

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self 
                                         selector:@selector(doneButtonClick:) 
                                             name:MPMoviePlayerWillExitFullscreenNotification 
                                           object:nil];
```

And selector method:

```
-(void)doneButtonClick:(NSNotification*)aNotification{
[myPlayer stop];
}
```

Comment: did you declare .h file myPlayer?

Comment: hai Selvam thank u so much but still iam gettig error [myPlayer stop]; here in selector method

Comment: iam not getting error now but my mpplayer not removing from super view i need to come back to table view

Comment: I have a table view that has a list videos. When I click on one it uses MPMoviePlayerController to play the corresponding video. I cannot figure out how to have the player return to the list-view when the video finishes or I click on the done button.
 my sample code is

Comment: - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    
    NSLog(@"didSelectRowAtIndexPath called");
    
   // cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"images-69.jpeg"];
    
    if (indexPath.row==0) {
         NSString *urlAsString = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource: [self.array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] ofType:@"mov"];
        
        NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:urlAsString];

Comment: myPlayer = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] init];
        myPlayer.shouldAutoplay = YES;
        myPlayer.repeatMode = MPMovieRepeatModeOne;
        myPlayer.fullscreen = YES;
        myPlayer.movieSourceType = MPMovieSourceTypeFile;
        myPlayer.scalingMode = MPMovieScalingModeAspectFit;
        myPlayer.contentURL =[NSURL fileURLWithPath:urlAsString];
        [self.view addSubview:myPlayer.view];
        
        [myPlayer.view setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 400)];
        [myPlayer setFullscreen:YES animated:YES];
        [myPlayer play];

Comment: [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                                 selector:@selector(doneButtonClick:)
                                                     name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification
                                                   object:nil];
    }
    
   }

-(void)doneButtonClick:(NSNotification*)aNotification
{
   
    [myPlayer stop];
    
  
}